# Custom value for Identity Column

Tags: sql-server

Suppose there is a table containing records of students from roll no 1 to 10. If we delete the record at roll number 4&5. Is it possible to enter new records at 4&5? Can anybody please help.

Comment: If you specify the roll number in the `INSERT` query, it will use it.

Comment: Depends on the schema of the table, and possibly the permissions that the user executing the code has (might need to be able to set IDENTITY_INSERT)

Comment: @Barmar: Not necessarily. If, for instance, the column for the roll number is also the identity column, and the `IDENTITY_INSERT` option is switched off, then you cannot insert records with specific roll numbers (4, 5). Like Rowland Shaw says, it depends on the schema.

Comment: @barmar but if we dont know which entery is blank in database then?I want entery at that blank position

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Reusing IDs is usually a bad idea.

Comment: This was my interview question today

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that using [SET IDENTITY_INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188059(v=sql.105).aspx), given that for the `StudentRollID` column, `IDENTITY(1, 1)` is specified. This means that as each row is inserted into the table, SQL Server will automatically increment this value by 1 starting with the number 1.

```
-- 1 - Retrieve all of the data 
-- from the dbo.Student table
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Student;
GO

-- 2 - Delete a single record
DELETE 
FROM dbo.Student
WHERE StudentRollID = 4;
GO

-- 3 - Verify the record was deleted
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Student;
GO

-- 4 - Insert the deleted record
-- Insert fails
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student]
 ([StudentRollID]
 ,[FirstName]
 ,[LastName] 
 ,[CreateDate])
VALUES
 (4
 ,'Bar'
 ,'Foo'
 ,'2014-12-04');
GO

-- 5 - Insert the deleted record
-- Insert succeeds
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Student] ON
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student]
 ([StudentRollID]
 ,[FirstName]
 ,[LastName] 
 ,[CreateDate])
VALUES
 (4
 ,'Bar'
 ,'Foo'
 ,'2014-12-04');
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Student] OFF
GO

-- 6 - Verify the data
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Student;
GO
```